# display/hide textbox based on drop down list

Tags: javascript, html

For-example I've got a code:

```
<form name="myform">
<table>
<td>
<select name="one" onchange="if (this.selectedIndex=='other'){this.myform['other'].style.visibility='visible'}else {this.myform['other'].style.visibility='hidden'};">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">3</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<input type="textbox" name="other" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
</td>
</table>
</form>
```

I need the textbox to appear when option "other" is selected. The above code is not working :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`selectedIndex` gives an index i.e. a number, so the index for "other" is 8, you can get the value of the selected option from the value property of the select element. To access the form a control is in use the elements form property `this.form`, also your you table cells should be in a row.

```
<form name="myform">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="one" onchange="if (this.value=='other'){this.form['other'].style.visibility='visible'}else {this.form['other'].style.visibility='hidden'};">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">3</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<input type="textbox" name="other" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: if you add another item tomorrow, the `selectedIndex` will not be `8`

Comment: @codingbiz what if you added one today?

Comment: Thank u for the solution @Musa. I was wondering if there's a way to handle the following problem. The "other" textbox is hidden until you select the value, but it still takes up space, so the design looks weird, because you just see an empty space. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: @kat_indo you can use the display property instead of  visibility.

Comment: Thank you for getting back on this one @Musa! I was able to figure it out after all by researching about it a bit more.

Answer (score 4):

```
    <form name="myform">
       <table>
         <td>
           <select name="one" onchange="if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value =='other'){document.myform['other'].style.visibility='visible'}else {document.myform['other'].style.visibility='hidden'};">
             <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
             <option value="1">1</option>
             <option value="2">3</option>
             <option value="3">3</option>
             <option value="4">4</option>
             <option value="5">5</option>
             <option value="6">6</option>
             <option value="7">7</option>
             <option value="other">Other</option>
          </select>
         <input type="textbox" name="other" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
       </td>
    </table>
 </form>​
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<form name="myform">
<table>
<td>
<select name="one" id="mySelect">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">3</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<input type="textbox" name="other" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
</td>
</table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#mySelect').bind('onchange',function(){
if (this.value==='other')
{
this.myform['other'].style.visibility='visible'
}
else {
this.myform['other'].style.visibility='hidden'};
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong but I won't downvote. Am sure somebody will. `this.selectedIndex=='other'` is wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#types').change(function () {
            if ($('#types').val() == 'Other') {
                $('#other').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#other').hide();
            }
        });
    });



<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

   <select id="types" name="types">
            <option value="Type 1">Type 1</option>
            <option value="Type 2">Type 2</option>
            <option value="Type 3">Type 3</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" id="other" name="other" style="display: none;" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.selectedIndex` returns an integer not a string. Something like 0,1,2 and probably 8 for 'others'. `8 == 'other'` can never be true

try this

```
onchange="if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value =='other')"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all enclose your **`td`** in a **`tr`** and then below is the DEMO

http://jsfiddle.net/3Snmh/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="one" onchange="if (this.value=='yes'){this.form['yes'].style.visibility='visible'}else {this.form['yes'].style.visibility='hidden'};">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
<option value="yes">yes</option>
<option value="no">no</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="yes" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: selected a value , gives an yes or no values . To select the value, you can get the value of the selected option from the value property of the select element. selected value is "yes",that time hidden text field will be show .value is "no" ,the text filed is hidden

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("select").change(function() {
            $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
                if ($(this).attr("value") == "class") {
                    $(".box").not(".class_name").hide();
                    $(".class_name").show();
                    $(".box").not(".class_name").val("");
                } 

                else if ($(this).attr("value") == "ref") {
                    $(".box").not(".ref_id").hide();
                    $(".ref_id").show();
                    $(".box").not(".ref_id").val("");
                }

                else {
                    $(".box").hide();
                }
            });
        }).change();
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
            <select>
                <option>Choose</option>
                <option value="class">Class</option>
                <option value="ref">Particular</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="class_name box">
            Class Name: <input type="text" name="c">
        </div>
        <div class="ref_id box">
            Reference_id : <input type="text" name="r">
        </div>
```