# hidden/show the text field when select dropdown list specified value

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

I start to generate my script from this solution find at this link [display/hide textbox based on drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158737/display-hide-textbox-based-on-drop-down-list)

In this case, the value must be a character value. But in my situation I need to value is a ID number specified get from mysql database.

This is my modified script and not work. When select the Other value, not display the textbox.

```
<form name="myform">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="one" onchange="if (this.value=='10000'){this.form['10000'].style.visibility='visible'}else {this.form['10000'].style.visibility='hidden'};">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">3</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="10000">Other</option>
                </select>
                <input type="textbox" name="10000" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

But this script workfine if change the value 10000 to OtherValue word.
How to modify this script?

Comment: What __exactly__ do you mean by _not work_?

Comment: I have update the post. Please read again.

Comment: @Frankie Check my answer. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Frankie Could you mark my response as the solution if you get the expected result?

Comment: @DamienGold yes, marked. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite your code like this.

```html
<form name="myform">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="one" onchange="if (this.value=='10000'){userselect.style.visibility='visible'}else {userselect.style.visibility='hidden'};">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="10000">Other</option>
                </select>
                <input type="textbox" name="10000" id="input" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<script>
var userselect = document.getElementById('input');
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking how to convert a string to a number, you can append a `+` sign before the string, like this:

```
var numberString = "3";                // the string "3"
var numericValue = +numberString;      // the number 3
```

Be aware that this converts to `NaN` if your string contains other than numeric values.

Comment: Looking for solution of Damien Gold.